# Add custom table record

Tags: acumatica

I have been trying to add custom DAC record which is the in database. But it is now working. Here is how I have tried to accomplish.

```
    public class SquarePOSTransactionInquiry : PXGraph<SquarePOSTransactionInquiry>
{

    public PXSave<MasterTable> Save;
    public PXCancel<MasterTable> Cancel;


    public PXFilter<MasterTable> MasterView;
    public PXSelect<INSquarePOSTransaction> INSquarePOSTransactions;

    public PXAction<MasterTable> calc;

    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Sync Square Transactions")]
    [PXProcessButton()]
    protected virtual IEnumerable Calc(PXAdapter adapter)
    {
        PXLongOperation.StartOperation(this, () =>
        {
            using (var scope = new PXTransactionScope())
            {
                INSquarePOSTransaction trans = new INSquarePOSTransaction();
                trans.TransacationCD = "new";
                trans.Description = "Another new";
                var test = this.INSquarePOSTransactions.Insert(trans);
                this.INSquarePOSTransactions.Cache.IsDirty = true;
                //this.INSquarePOSTransactions.Update(trans);
                this.Actions.PressSave();
                scope.Complete();
            }

        });
        return adapter.Get();
    }

    public SquarePOSTransactionInquiry()
    {

    }

    [Serializable]
    public class MasterTable : IBqlTable
    {

    }
}
```

I tried setting cache IsDirty property to false, but that didn't help too. But the strange part is updating the DAC is working. I have even looked into other Business Logic codes from other pages and it looks same like I have tried above. Could you please tell me what I am missing?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within the method that you pass to StartOperation(),
you have to create a new instance of the graph and invoke the processing method on that instance.

Comment: Thanks. It worked. This is how I have put the code now. 
`INSquarePOSTransaction trans = new INSquarePOSTransaction();
trans.TransacationCD = "new new";
trans.Description = "Another new new";
var graph = PXGraph.CreateInstance<SquarePOSTransactionInquiry>();
var res = graph.INSquarePOSTransactions.Insert(trans);
graph.Actions.PressSave();
scope.Complete();
graph.INSquarePOSTransactions.View.RequestRefresh();`

But the weird part is, though database table contains new record:
https://www.screencast.com/t/aTaMfa3Ta4a

Acumatica page:
https://www.screencast.com/t/cd0sh1b6ZV